# PHP Script running without redirection

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, forms

I have a database with two tables: accounts and recipes(each have their own ID column).

I have a page that displays all the recipes. I want to enable users to add recipes to their favourites in accounts table. Once user is logged in, $_SESSION['user_id'] is set.

I have script that will add the recipe id to the favourites in accounts table, but I don't know how to run it without redirecting from the page that displays all recipes.

Here is what i have so far:

**_view.php**

```
    <?php
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM recipes");

    if ( $result->num_rows == 0 ){
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Error!";
        echo "<div class='error-mess'>" . $_SESSION['message'] . "</div>";
    }
    else { 
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $slug = $row['slug'];
                $ingr = json_decode($row['ingr']);
                $ingr_count= count($ingr);
                $id = $row['id'];
                echo '<div class="container recipe mb-2">';
                echo  '<img class="" src="/images/recipes/';
                echo  $row['img'];
                echo '"/>';
                echo  '<div class="title-cats"><a href = "/recipe_preview.php?slug=' . $slug . '">';
                echo  $row['title'];
                echo  '</a></div>';
                echo  '<h4>Ingredients:</h4><br>';
                for($i = 0; $i<$ingr_count;$i++){
                    $num = $i + 1;
                    echo $num . '. ';
                    $ingrs = json_decode($ingr[$i],true);
                    print_r($ingrs[0]);
                    echo '<br>';
                }
                echo  '<br><a href="/recipe_preview.php?slug=' . $slug . '"><button type="submit" class="btn" name="add">Read More</button></a>';

//favourites link
                echo '<a href="/libs/_favourite.php" id="favourite" data-id="'.$id.'"><span class="fa fa-heart ml-3"></span></a>';

                echo  '</div><hr>';
            }
    }
```

**_favourite.php**

```
<?php
//relationship
require 'db.php';
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
//$favourite_id = $_POST['fav'];
$favourite_id = $_GET["id"];
echo $favourite_id;
echo $user_id;

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT favourites FROM accounts WHERE id ='$user_id'");
if ( $result === null) {//doesnt work
    $favs = array();
    array_push($favs,$favourite_id);
    $new_favs = json_encode($favs);
    echo 'null';
}
else{
    $favs = array();
    $result = json_decode($result,true);
    array_push($favs, $result);
    array_push($favs,$favourite_id);
    $new_favs = json_encode($favs);
}
$sql = "UPDATE accounts SET favourites ='$new_favs' WHERE id = '$user_id'";
if ( $mysqli->query($sql)){
    echo '<div class="error-mess">Recipe sucessfully saved!</div>';
}
else{
    echo '<div class="error-mess">NOT</div>';

}
```

.js -jquery library is there

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#favourite').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevents the default behaviour of following the link

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: $(this).attr('href'),
            data: {
                id: $(this).data('id'),
            },
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(data) {
                // do whatever here
                if(data === 'success') {
                    alert('Updated succeeded');
                } else {
                    alert(data); // perhaps an error message?
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It seems that the link to `_favourite.php` is handled with AJAX, so it shouldn't be refreshing the page. Do you mean that the list of favorites is not updated after adding a new favorite? What specifically is going wrong?

Comment: Why you kept view and favorites page different ? Your favorite action can be performed from within the view page itself .

Comment: @showdev It doesn't refresh the page, as it should not, but the _favourite.php is not being ran- the list is not updated.

Comment: @PHPWeb Just to keep the code tidier...